# Splitting cells in Google Sheets based on content

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm attempting to sort through a decent amount of data sent to me via Google Sheets. It's about 400 rows but will grow so I'm wanting to make this dynamic. There is a cell named `Location` that has data in it such as `Los Angeles, California` or `Salt Lake City, UT`

My goal is to break each of these cells into a `City` and `State` cell. Replacing the current `Location`column with `City` and putting the state into the column to the right of it called `State`.

Any help on where to get started, tools to use, or already in-place functions would be great. This is going to be hosted through Google Drive to keep it easily accessible, so VBA probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to use script:

Let's say `Location` is column A and data starts at cell A2. In B2 you could put

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,",")))
```

To hide the "N/A" that is returned for blank columns, you could put

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,","))))
```